# Python - Looping in array value into excel file using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, xlsxwriter

I am trying to see if I could enter values of an array into a spreadsheet using xlsxwriter module. Given below is a view of the array I am working with:

```
0(5339, '2017-09')
1(670, '2017-10')
2(3268, '2017-11')
3(7645, '2017-12')
4(9999, '2018-01')
5(11987, '2018-02')
6(14354, '2018-03')
7(15782, '2018-04')
8(15465, '2018-05')
9(1473, '2018-06')
10(1661, '2018-07')
11(5679, '2018-08')
12(6927, '2018-09')
```

Could anyone assist, thanks..

Comment: What did you try so far and what didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('YOUR_FILE.XLSX')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Start from the first cell row 0 and column 0
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate through the array you have and unpack the tuple at each index
for elm1, elm2 in your_array:
    worksheet.write(row, col, elm1)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, elm2)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```